# What is the Python code to show the feature importance in SVM?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, svm

How can I show the important features that contribute to the SVM model along with the feature name?

My code is shown below,

First I Imported the modules

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
```

Then I divided my data into features and variables

```
y = df_new[['numeric values']]
X = df_new.drop('numeric values', axis=1).values
```

Then I Setup the pipeline

```
steps = [('scalar', StandardScaler()),
         ('SVM', SVC(kernel='linear'))]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
```

Then I Specified my the hyperparameter space

```
parameters = {'SVM__C':[1, 10, 100],
              'SVM__gamma':[0.1, 0.01]}
```

I Created a train and test sets

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=21)
```

Instantiate the GridSearchCV object: cv

```
cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline,param_grid = parameters,cv=5)
```

Fit to the training set

```
cv.fit(X_train,y_train.values.ravel())
```

Predict the labels of the test set: y_pred

```
y_pred = cv.predict(X_test)

feature_importances = cv.best_estimator_.feature_importances_
```

The error message I get

> 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Please make sure the question has a clear problem description.

Comment: The problem is, I want to extract see the important features of my data.
I already use
feature_importances = cv.best_estimator_.feature_importances_
but I get 
" 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_' "

Comment: So you have a code, which produces an error, make sure to have the code and the full error traceback in the question.

Comment: Suppose, you have to look at this article:
https://medium.com/@aneesha/visualising-top-features-in-linear-svm-with-scikit-learn-and-matplotlib-3454ab18a14d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I  understood is that,  lets suppose you are building a model with 100 feature and you want to know which feature is more important and which is less if this is the case ?

Just try Uni-variate feature selection method, Its very basic method and you can play with this before going to advance methods for your data. Sample code is provided **scikit-learn** it self. You can modified it as per  your requirement.

```
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets, svm
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile, f_classif

###############################################################################
# import some data to play with

# The iris dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# Some noisy data not correlated
E = np.random.uniform(0, 0.1, size=(len(iris.data), 20))

# Add the noisy data to the informative features
X = np.hstack((iris.data, E))
y = iris.target

###############################################################################
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()

X_indices = np.arange(X.shape[-1])

###############################################################################
# Univariate feature selection with F-test for feature scoring
# We use the default selection function: the 10% most significant features
selector = SelectPercentile(f_classif, percentile=10)
selector.fit(X, y)
scores = -np.log10(selector.pvalues_)
scores /= scores.max()
plt.bar(X_indices - .45, scores, width=.2,
        label=r'Univariate score ($-Log(p_{value})$)', color='g')

###############################################################################
# Compare to the weights of an SVM
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, y)

svm_weights = (clf.coef_ ** 2).sum(axis=0)
svm_weights /= svm_weights.max()

plt.bar(X_indices - .25, svm_weights, width=.2, label='SVM weight', color='r')

clf_selected = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf_selected.fit(selector.transform(X), y)

svm_weights_selected = (clf_selected.coef_ ** 2).sum(axis=0)
svm_weights_selected /= svm_weights_selected.max()

plt.bar(X_indices[selector.get_support()] - .05, svm_weights_selected,
        width=.2, label='SVM weights after selection', color='b')


plt.title("Comparing feature selection")
plt.xlabel('Feature number')
plt.yticks(())
plt.axis('tight')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Code ref. 
http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/auto_examples/plot_feature_selection.html

**Note;**
For each feature, this method will plot  p-values for the univariate feature selection and the corresponding weights of an SVM. This method  selects those feature which shows  larger SVM weights.

Comment: Yes, you did understand my question correctly. But why should I use univariate method to see my features when SVM has already done it for me ? I want to see the features that SVM has chosen for predicting the data.

Comment: Can you please explain this part 'svm.SVC(kernel='linear')'

Comment: Just created clf instance to load classifier to fit data for model building using     linear kernel. As u can choose different kernel methods for prediction which is also depends upon you data.

Comment: @MajidHelmy For a straightforward model building, classifier itself does not choose and omit features automatically. It will compute model on the basis of all the available features, wither they are useful or not. This is why we perform feature selection step before final model building. Uni variate feature selection evaluate the contribution of each and every feature for predication error using SVM. It will tell you the weight of each and every feature for model accuracy. On this basis you can select the most useful feature